# Selenium fails to detect incorrect text

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Selenium Web Driver with Java. I have the following code:

```
<div class="missingData">
            <p class="notification_text" id="notification_text">Please review the following questions<br></p>
        </div>
```

I have an assertEquals to check if the text is present on the page. It seemed to be running fine, but then I tested the method by putting junk text to test:

```
assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.id("notification_text")).getText(), "salkjdal");
```

Unfortunately, the test still passes. What is going on? The junk text is definitely not on the page.

Comment: I would, but it's not out on production yet and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post the code before release. However, I just realized that the issue probably doesn't have to do with Selenium. For some reason the assertEquals method isn't working. I should be able to figure this out and post what's going on. Stay tuned...

Comment: id may be duplicated on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! However, I figured out the issue. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe my issue was that I had assertEquals imported from the junit package instead of the testng package. I'm creating TestNG tests so I'm guessing that import caused some issues. I also debugged by making sure I was reading in the string correctly. In my case, I did this:

```
String abc = driver.findElement(By.id("notification_text")).getText();
```

The text was what I expected, and if I couldn't figure out the assertEquals issue, I could have also used the basic String.equals() to circumvent the problem in my case.